# Conditional statement to show registration success message is showing the error message even when successful?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap, use-state

I wasn't sure how to phrase the title but basically, I am following a tutorial to create a login/registration and I am currently trying to display a message indicating whether the registration attempt was successful or not.

Here is my Register.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from "axios";

export default function Register() {
    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [register, setRegister] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // prevent the form from refreshing the whole page
        e.preventDefault();
    //set configuration
        const configuration = {
            method: "post",
            url: "https://nodejs-mongodb-auth-app-learn.herokuapp.com/register",
            data: {
                email,
                password,
            },
        };
    // API call
        axios(configuration)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                setRegister=(true);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                error= new Error;
            })
        
    };

    return (
        <>
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <Form onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>
            {/* email */}
            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={email} 
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Enter email" 
                />
            </Form.Group>

            {/* password */}
            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    type="password" 
                    name="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Enter password" 
                />
            </Form.Group>

            {/* submit button */}
            <Button 
                variant="primary" 
                type="submit"
                onClick={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}
            >
                Register
            </Button>

            {/* display success message */}
            {register ? (
                <p className="text-success">You Are Registered Successfully</p>
            ) :  ( 
                <p className="text-danger">You Are Not Registered</p>
            )}
        </Form>
        </>
    )
};
```

The successful registration will log on the console, but either setRegister is not updating register to true, or my conditional statement is incorrect in some way?

It always shows "You Are Not Registered".

Comment: Typo — remove the = after setRegister. It’s a function call, not a variable assignment

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to ser an state using useState hook is:
e.g

```
const [register, setRegister] = useState(false);

setRegister(true)
```